# Why is my "X" not showing through the transparent rectangle?

Tags: three.js, textures, transparent

This code shows 2 rectangles with "X"s behind a transparent rectangle.  The top one has a reddish background -- the "X" show through the front rectangle as it should.  The bottom rectangle has the default transparent background -- the "X" doesn't show through the front rectangle as I would like.  Maybe there is an "alpha.." parameter I'm missing?  TIA.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> threejs texture transparency </title>
    <style type="text/css">
canvas { outline:1px dotted black; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";
  var renderer, camera, world, geometry, material, mesh;
  var js3canvas, js3w, js3h, canvas, ctx, texture;
window.onload = function() {
  "use strict";
  // the basic 3js
  js3canvas = document.getElementById("js3canvas");
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas:js3canvas } );
  js3w = js3canvas.width;
  js3h = js3canvas.height;
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, js3w/js3h, 1, 200);
  camera.position.z = 75;
  camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
  world = new THREE.Scene();
  world.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);

  // a greenish transparent rectangle at z=+1
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 50);
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0x55aa55, transparent:true, opacity:0.5 } );
  world.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));

  doRect("top"); // a REDDISH rectangle at z=-1 with a texture of a black "X"
  doRect("bot"); // a TRANSPARENT rectangle at z=-1 with a texture of a black "X"
  renderer.render( world, camera );
};
function doRect(topbot) { // a rectangle with a texture
  // first, the canvas for the texture
  if (topbot == "top") canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2"); // top rectangle
  else canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3"); // bot rectangle
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (topbot == "top") { // top only, reddish background
    ctx.fillStyle = "#aa5555"; 
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,250,50);
  } // bot is left default transparent
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000000"; // black lines to make "X"
  ctx.moveTo(0,0); ctx.lineTo(250,50);
  ctx.moveTo(0,50); ctx.lineTo(250,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  // second, the texture
  texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; // eliminates console.log msg
  texture.needsUpdate = true; // needed
  // third, the rectangle with the texture
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,10);
  if (topbot == "top") { // top rectangle with "X" texture, reddish background
    geometry.translate(0,10,-1); // move up
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture, transparent:false } );
    // If this material is transparent(true) then the "X" doesn't show through.
  } else {               // bottom rectangle with "X" texture, default(transparent) background
    geometry.translate(0,-10,-1); // move down
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture, transparent:true, opacity:1.0 } );
    // This material has to be transparent to get a transparent background for the texture.
    // But then the "X" doesn't show through.
  }
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // and finally the mesh
  world.add(mesh);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="js3canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas><br />
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="250" height="50"></canvas><br />
    <canvas id="canvas3" width="250" height="50"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT for Mugen87:
  add "side:THREE.DoubleSide, " to all materials,
  add these 2 statements in the appropriate places:

```
  mesh.renderOrder = 1;
  animate();
```

and add this function:

```
function animate() {
  renderer.render( world, camera );
  world.rotation.y += .01;
  if (world.rotation.y < 3.1416) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Now the bottom rectangle is not transparent?
I'll be looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a depth sorting issue. Both transparent objects (the green plane mesh and the transparent X) are placed at the same position in 3D space. Hence, they are rendered according to their order in the scene graph. For the correct result, you have to ensure that the green plane is rendered last. You can influence the default sorting of the renderer by defining [Object3D.renderOrder](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder).

```js
var renderer, camera, world, geometry, material, mesh;
var js3canvas, js3w, js3h, canvas, ctx, texture;

// the basic 3js
js3canvas = document.getElementById("js3canvas");
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas:js3canvas } );
js3w = js3canvas.width;
js3h = js3canvas.height;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, js3w/js3h, 1, 200);
camera.position.z = 75;
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
world = new THREE.Scene();
world.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);

// a greenish transparent rectangle at z=+1
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 50);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0x55aa55, transparent:true, opacity:0.5 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.renderOrder = 1;
world.add(mesh);

doRect("top"); // a REDDISH rectangle at z=-1 with a texture of a black "X"
doRect("bot"); // a TRANSPARENT rectangle at z=-1 with a texture of a black "X"

renderer.render( world, camera );

function doRect(topbot) { // a rectangle with a texture
  // first, the canvas for the texture
  if (topbot == "top") canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2"); // top rectangle
  else canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3"); // bot rectangle
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (topbot == "top") { // top only, reddish background
    ctx.fillStyle = "#aa5555"; 
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,250,50);
  } // bot is left default transparent
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000000"; // black lines to make "X"
  ctx.moveTo(0,0); ctx.lineTo(250,50);
  ctx.moveTo(0,50); ctx.lineTo(250,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  // second, the texture
  texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; // eliminates console.log msg
  texture.needsUpdate = true; // needed
  // third, the rectangle with the texture
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,10);
  if (topbot == "top") { // top rectangle with "X" texture, reddish background
    geometry.translate(0,10,-1); // move up
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture } );
    // If this material is transparent(true) then the "X" doesn't show through.
  } else {               // bottom rectangle with "X" texture, default(transparent) background
    geometry.translate(0,-10,-1); // move down
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture, transparent:true, opacity:1.0 } );
    // This material has to be transparent to get a transparent background for the texture.
    // But then the "X" doesn't show through.
  }
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // and finally the mesh
  world.add(mesh);
}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
canvas { 
 outline: 1px dotted black; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r113/build/three.js"></script>

<canvas id="js3canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas><br />
<canvas id="canvas2" width="250" height="50"></canvas><br />
<canvas id="canvas3" width="250" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow -- fast results!  Thanks!  I'll be looking into this.  Is getting three.js from githack.com better than from threejs.org?

Comment: I added a followup question to my question (is that allowed?)

Comment: In general, it's better to make a new question. BTW: I've picked the library from `githack.com` so the version `R113` is locked. Using `threejs.org` would automatically upgrade the library on a release and probably break the live example at some point.